# Flex 4.5.1 - Mobile Image Covering Entire screen

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, dpi, screen-size

I want to have an image that has to cover the entire screen or at least one of the sides so that it keeps its aspect ratio.

How do I do that considering the various screen sizes and DPI?

Comment: If you are developing a mobile app, then Capabilities.screenResolutionX should return it. But it has a bug(?) - if you debug it returns your monitor's resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.screen
```

returns the screen rectangle, and

```
 FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI
```

returns the DPI of the application.

But in Flex you can simply set an s:Image control's width to 100% of the view, then it will cover your screen. (and dont set the height, Flex will figure it out for you)